# mouse events (onmousedown, onclick, onmouseup) aren't captured on <object> tag in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

When I add mouse events to an object tag in jsx the event doesn't get set

```
handleMouse(event) {
  console.log(event.screenX+ ' '+event.screenY);
  console.log(event.target);
}

<object width="400" height="800" data={this.props.document} id="pdf_object" 
    onMouseDown={this.handleMouse} onMouseUp={this.handdleMouse}>PDF should load here</object>
```

However if I add the event listener to a containing div it works:

```
<div onMouseDown={this.handleMouse} onMouseUp={this.handdleMouse}>
  <object width="400" height="800" data={this.props.document} 
     id="pdf_object">PDF should load here</object>
</div>
```

I'm wondering why this is the case when I can add mouse events to an object tag in html

```
<object width="400" height="800" data="ex2.pdf" 
    onmousedown="console.log('down')" onmouseup="console.log('up')"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example it works well on the Object as well

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.mouseDown = this.mouseDown.bind(this);
    this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this);
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  mouseDown(event){
    console.log("Mouse Down Event");
    console.log(event.screenX+ ' '+event.screenY);
  }

  mouseUp(event){
    console.log("Mouse Up Event");
    console.log(event.screenX+ ' '+event.screenY);
  }

  click(){
    console.log("Mouse Clicked");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>   
        <object width="400" height="800" data={this.props.document} 
          onMouseDown={this.mouseDown}
          onMouseUp={this.mouseUp}
          onClick = {this.click}
         id="pdf_object">PDF should load here</object>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```